# Transforming long-format time-period data for analysis

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have long-format time-period data including the use of different care episodes in time. I am struggling to prepare my data for analyzing the distribution of the use of different care episodes in time.

**How can I transform my long-format time-period data into the following way:**

[image]

**Data**

"time_of_diagnosis" is the start of care continuum.

```
library("tidyverse")    
df = read_csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/78pthc4skndfzi0/care_episodes.csv?dl=1")

df
```

[image]

This calculates "start day" and "end day" but doesn't help in showing days between.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(start_day = episode_start - time_of_diagnosis,
         end_day = episode_end - time_of_diagnosis)
```

**In the end, I would like to plot something like this**

[image]

PS! Tidyverse solutions are especially appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This might be along the lines of what you're looking for, where `day` and `date` is the day of each recorded event (each patient and incident recorded)?

```r
library("tidyverse")    
df <-  read_csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/78pthc4skndfzi0/care_episodes.csv?dl=1",
                show_col_types = FALSE)

df |> 
  mutate(start_day = as.integer(episode_start - min(time_of_diagnosis)),
         end_day = as.integer(episode_end - min(time_of_diagnosis)),
         length = end_day - start_day + 1) |> 
  uncount(length, .id = "day_n") |> 
  mutate(day = start_day + day_n,
         date = min(time_of_diagnosis) + lubridate::days(day-1)) |> 
  select(ID, time_of_diagnosis, episode_type, episode_start, episode_end, day, date)

#> # A tibble: 1,114 × 7
#>       ID time_of_diagnosis episode_type episode_st…¹ episode_…²   day date      
#>    <dbl> <date>            <chr>        <date>       <date>     <int> <date>    
#>  1  2973 2010-04-13        A            2010-04-13   2010-04-20     1 2010-04-13
#>  2  2973 2010-04-13        A            2010-04-13   2010-04-20     2 2010-04-14
#>  3  2973 2010-04-13        A            2010-04-13   2010-04-20     3 2010-04-15
#>  4  2973 2010-04-13        A            2010-04-13   2010-04-20     4 2010-04-16
#>  5  2973 2010-04-13        A            2010-04-13   2010-04-20     5 2010-04-17
#>  6  2973 2010-04-13        A            2010-04-13   2010-04-20     6 2010-04-18
#>  7  2973 2010-04-13        A            2010-04-13   2010-04-20     7 2010-04-19
#>  8  2973 2010-04-13        A            2010-04-13   2010-04-20     8 2010-04-20
#>  9 10046 2013-06-18        B            2013-06-18   2013-06-23  1163 2013-06-18
#> 10 10046 2013-06-18        B            2013-06-18   2013-06-23  1164 2013-06-19
#> # … with 1,104 more rows, and abbreviated variable names ¹​episode_start,
#> #   ²​episode_end
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>